# How Does Doctor Strange's cloak of levitation work inside the mirror dimension?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange

In the Doctor Strange movie, his cloak of levitation only worked when he entered the mirror dimension but was afterwards never used in that dimension. (If the cloak would have worked, he could have very easily escaped Kaecilius without falling down all the time and leave the mirror dimension.)

Was this a plot hole or is there a reason behind its malfunction inside the mirror dimenion?

Comment: How do you know it "didn't work" inside the mirror dimension? He was fighting Kaecilius, not trying to get away...

Comment: It levitated him into Dark Dimension at the end of the movie, while they were outside the Mirror Dimension. There is no relationship (AFAIK) between the Cloak of Levitation and the Mirror Dimension.

Comment: Well then why didn't he leave the mirror dimension? He did "try" to leave but then just let himself fall onto the bus where Stan Lee was reading a book.

Comment: The cloak is portrayed as sentient, so maybe the cloak didn't want Strange to leave, seeing as it also didn't want Strange grabbing the Axe

Comment: Of course it works in the mirror world. There are several moments in the mirror world where he and Mordo are shown falling and landing safely due to the their respective magical imbued objects (the cloak and the boots).

Comment: @sanpaco Yeah, Napoleon Wilson edited it as though I wanted to know if it worked in the mirror dimension when I simply wanted to know how it worked in the mirror dimension.

Comment: @sanpaco I asked specifically because Strange didn't use it to help him leave the mirror dimension and instead was falling all over the place.

Comment: Also, I'm not a fan that you downvoted my question because someone seems to have understood it wrongly and edited it in a way that leads other people in the wrong direction.

Comment: The claim that his cloak "was never used" was in your question from the start, and is untrue, so the edits to your question aren't the problem... it was already confusing for me (I mis-read it twice) as soon as you posted it.

Comment: I said "was afterwards never used" because I couldn't remember if it was hard landings or if the cloak floated him safely onto buildings when he fell. I never said it didn't work at all in the mirror dimension and in the end the question is still about whether or not it was a plot hole or if DLE's explanation is reasonable enough. Which to me it is reasonable enough unless someone in the future has a better explanation.

Comment: @Alox I did not downvote your question, but given it seems to be misunderstood by several of us here it is not surprising that someone did downvote it. I suggest you edit your question to clarify what it is that you are asking. If someone made an edit that altered your original intent then you can rollback that edit. I'm sorry that there has been confusion on your question.

Comment: @Alox you should be able to edit your question to reword it to what you actually intend the question to be.  your original wording was very vague, and I can understand why it was edited to try and make it clearer.

Comment: Given that he had just come into possession of the cloak and it is noted to be "fickle", it wouldn't surprise me if it only worked for him some of the time, especially when he first gets it. As time goes on he may gain better control of it, but we are seeing a relatively novice sorcerer with a new tool that he doesn't fully understand

Answer (score 2):

The cloak always worked in all situations throughout the movie. No scene or moment showed the cloak failing. There is no link or issue with it working in the mirror dimension. In all falling scenes, it slowed his fall. Otherwise he or any normal person would have died.